# How to hide PickerView by click on textview

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

How to hide Picker when date is selected?

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    countryCodeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@",[array_countryCode objectAtIndex:row]];

    [countryCodeButton setTitle:countryCodeString forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yep.. i got my solution

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

[picker removeFromSupperView];

}

Answer (score 0):

we can hide pickerview on its component seletion as below...

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

countryCodeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@",[array_countryCode objectAtIndex:row]];

[countryCodeButton setTitle:countryCodeString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[picker removeFromSupperView]; }